# UNIX: How to display each letter once in a list

Tags: unix

I have made a command that gives the following output

A
A 
A
A
A
A
C
C
C
Q
Q

I need to display each letter once only. I have tried tr -s 'A-Z' but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: you need to provide the code that generates this output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command doesn't work in view of the spaces.
Remove them first and insert them when finished:

```
echo "A A A A A A C C C Q Q" | tr -d ' ' | tr -s 'A-Z' | sed 's/./& /g;s/ s//'
```

Another possibility is something like

```
echo "A A A A A A C C C Q Q" | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '
```

A more tricky one:

```
echo "A A A A A A C C C Q Q" | sed -r ':m s/(.) \1/\1/g;t m'
```